# Safari on iOS inconsistently recognizes content height

Tags: ios, html, css, mobile-safari, smooth-scrolling

From my testing this is specific to Safari iOs issue.

[The bug is on this page.](http://dev2.meetandsee.com/careers.html)

Basically on iOS, when expanding the last content item, the browsers doesn't always scroll the content but scrolls the page.

It's inconsistent behavior which happens to the last section item no matter what I do.  I've tried adding in another section element to the DOM as a hack to make it work properly but it still behaves the same.

The height is expanded based of max-height parameters so that dynamic content cant be expanded correctly by the js.

Been spending hours looking at this and it's at a point where I need some other eyes to take a look.  Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's after asking a question you find the answer.... I was able to fix this by removing a css height rule on a parent container that was using the new vh rule. I changed it to use 100% vs 80vh and it's behaving as expected. Hope this helps someone else.